# Как создать динамическую таблицу?

Tags: java, maven, jsf, web-apps

Идея такая: пользователь создает на странице запрос типа:

```
WHERE ID EQUAL(=) 123 AND Статус NOT IN qweqwe AND Создатель BETWEEN string1 AND string3
```

На основании этого запроса нужно сформировать таблицу (запросы могут быть абсолютно любые). По приведенному выше запросу видно, что нужно создать три столбца "ID" "Статус" и "Создатель".

Какая есть идея: в `static List<QueryTemplate> queries = new ArrayList<>()` хранятся атрибуты. С помощью этого списка можно получить имена атрибутов (столбцов) и => их количество.

Но вопрос остаётся актуальным: как создавать динамические таблицы, в которых количество столбцов и их имена будут зависеть от выбора пользователя на предыдущей странице?

Я знаю, как создавать статическую таблицу (и она как раз пока что у меня и висит):

```
<p:column headerText="Name">
    <h:outputText value="#{obj.getName()}"/>
</p:column>

<p:column headerText="ID">
    <h:outputText value="#{obj.getId()}"/>
</p:column>

<p:column headerText="Date">
    <h:outputText value="#{obj.getCreationDate()}"/>
</p:column>
```

Помогите разобраться, пожалуйста.

Comment: http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/data/datatable/columns.xhtml

Comment: Рассмотрите вариант использования NoSQL решений, например, mongodb. Там вы сможете с лёгкостью организовать любую структуру документа, исходя из ваших требований.

Answer (score 1):

Необходимо воспользоваться такой штукой: `<c:forEach>`, предварительно её прописав: `xmlns:c="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"`.

Далее создаем таблицу (.xhtml):

```
    <p:dataTable>
        <c:forEach items="#{attrsBean.queries}" var="obj">
            <p:column headerText="#{attrsBean.Plus()}"/>
        </c:forEach>
    </p:dataTable>
```

Так мы получаем размер листа, а соответственно кол-во столбцов `items="#{attrsBean.queries}"`.

Имя атрибута выдается по конкретному номеру `queries.get(0).getAttrName()` - выведет первое имя, `queries.get(1).getAttrName()` - второе, и так далее. Соответственно, в классе прописываем метод получения имени (.java):

```
private int n = 0;

public String Plus(){
        String nn = queries.get(n).getAttrName();
        n++;
        return nn;
    }
```

И прописываем его в имя колонки `column headerText="#{attrsBean.Plus()}"`